# Let user scroll "wrapped" image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to leave a world map under user control for scrolling, but have it wrap when the user scrolls to either end.  The scrolling is not animated; the map only scrolls when users scroll it.  Ideally, you could hold the mouse down on a scrollbar arrow and scroll forever.  (The map is 2246 wide, plus a duplicated part 800 wide--the width of the visible area.)

The following works sporadically in Chrome, but almost not at all in Firefox or Safari (on a Mac).

```
function scrollAndWrap() {
    scr = document.getElementById("map").scrollLeft;
    if (scr > 2246-10) document.getElementById("map").scrollLeft -= 2246;
    else if (scr < 10) document.getElementById("map").scrollLeft += 2246;
}

<div style="width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:auto;" onscroll="scrollAndWrap();">
    <img src="ProjMap.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a background image? Hard to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: How would a background image help? 
My fiddle doesn't work at all:  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/blockard/sp4jjoz5/2/)